# imprimir una variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, print

Por ejemplo:

```
edad = 18

print("Tengo %d años) % edad
```

Según me dijeron debía formularlo así pero me tira este error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: Buenas, te aconsejo completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tour), [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), para saber como formular mejor tu pregunta, siempre será más fácil responder. :)

Comment: Estoy por calificarlo como un error tipográfico, faltan las comillas de cierre (lo cual causa de primeras un error de sintaxis, no el error mostrado) y el paréntesis de cierre de la llamada a `print` está en mal lugar (lo cual causa el error mostrado porque se aplica el formato sobre la salida de `print` que es `None` no sobre la cadena): `print("Tengo %d años" % edad)`. En Python 3 se puede usar y se recomienda `str.format` -> `print("Tengo {} años).format(edad)` o en Python >= 3.6 literales de cadena formateados `print(f"Tengo {edad} años)`

Answer (score 1):

La sintaxis es

```
edad = 18
print("tengo %d años" % edad)
```

Y sí funciona en python3.

Answer (score -1):

En Python 3.x ya no se permite el uso de %.

**Edición**

En https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html leí

> A new system for built-in string formatting operations replaces the % string formatting operator.(However, the % operator is still supported; it will be deprecated in Python 3.1 and removed from the language at some later time.) 
>   Read PEP 3101 for the full scoop.

**Fin**

Se debe hacer uso de .format.

Por ejemplo en tu caso:

```
edad=18
frase="Tengo {} años".format(edad)
print(frase)
```

Comment: muchas gracias!!

Comment: En [tag:python-3.x] todavía se permite el uso de `%` para formato. Se denomina [formato printf](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=format#printf-style-string-formatting) por su semejanza con el `printf`de C. El código que hay en la pregunta es incorrecto, por lo que no es imposible saber qué produce ese error.